# How to insert HTML tag in Python?

Tags: python, html, django

I have a class like this, that generates hyperlinks:

```
class getLink(obj):
    def __init__(self, text, url):
        self.text = self.Argument(text)
        self.url = self.Argument(url)
    def render(self, context):
        return "%s %s" % (html.link(self.text(context), self.url(context)))


def link(text, url):
    return mark_safe('<a href="%s">%s</a>' % (url, title))
```

Then to get a Link I do thus:

```
getLink(text=_('Test'),fn.getUrl())
```

HTML result:

```
<a href="/python/tests/">Test</a>
```

I want to wrap the link inside a `<div>` and another inside a `<li>` tag. I tried to add the tags directly in `getLink()` but doesn't work 
`getLink("<div>" + text=_('Test'),fn.getUrl() + "</div>")`. I'm newbie in Python so sorry if I'm wrong.

Thanks for you help!

Comment: `getLink("<div>" + text=_('Test'),fn.getUrl() + "</div>")` is invalid syntax in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap the result of your function call in the tags you want?

```
wrapped_in_div = "<div>" + getLink(text=_('Test'),fn.getUrl()) + "</div>"
wrapped_in_li = "<li>" + getLink(text=_('Test'),fn.getUrl()) + "</li>"
```

Or you can make use of `format`:

```
wrapped_in_div = "<{0}>{1}</{0}>".format("div", getLink(text=_('Test'),fn.getUrl()))
wrapped_in_li = "<{0}>{1}</{0}>".format("li", getLink(text=_('Test'),fn.getUrl()))
```

Answer (score 2):

I hardly understand where your code is from and if you are able to modify it.

But if you are, why not change the *link* function and wrap the link directly in there?

Like this :

```
def link(text, url):
    return mark_safe('<div><a href="%s">%s</a></div>' % (url, title))
```

Maybe you should be more explicit.

Comment: Thank you for answer! but I want to wrap the link inside a `<div>` and another inside a `<li>` tag without creating another method or class. With your solution I can not change the tag `<div>` to another tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
@app.route('/')
def googlelink():
    return ('<div><a href="%s">%s</a></div>' % ("https://www.google.com","Google"))
```